# how to select input field in listed form with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-selectors

I got several forms listed through a loop at one page such like this: (extract)

```
if(mysql_num_rows($r)>0): 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)):  ?>
        <form id="myForm" action="save_fb.php" method="post"> 

        Title: <input type="text" name="fb_title" value="<?php echo $row['fb_title']; ?>" /><br> 

    <a href="javascript:;" class="save_fb" id="<?php echo $row['fb_id']; ?>"></a>


        </form>
```

in my ajax request i do something like:

```
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: $("input:text[name=fb_titel]").val()+$(this).attr("id"),
   url: "save_fb.php",
   success: function(msg)
   {
    $("span#votes_count"+the_id).fadeOut();
    $("span#votes_count"+the_id).html(msg);
    $("span#votes_count"+the_id).fadeIn();
   }
  });
 });
```

now I get as an result always first row and not the row where the link was clicked however the $(this) works fine but I do not know how to combine...  Anyone know how the data line should look like?

Thanks for any hint =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: $(this).prev("input[name=fb_title]").val()+$(this).attr("id"),
   url: "save_fb.php",
   success: function(msg)
   {
    $("span#votes_count"+the_id).fadeOut().html(msg).fadeIn();
   }
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the third line of your script like so....

```
data: $(this).parent().find("input:text[name=fb_title]").val()+$(this).attr("id"),
```

Your current script finds the first instance of any `<input name="fb_title">`. If you use this it will only find the `<input name="fb_title">` in the same form as the link you clicked.

Comment: Note, I corrected your misspelling of 'fb_titel' to 'fb_title' too.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP/HTML:

```
mysql_num_rows($r)>0): 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)):  ?>
        <form id="myForm-<?php echo $row['fb_id']; ?>" action="save_fb.php" method="post"> 

        Title: <input type="text" name="fb_title" value="<?php echo $row['fb_title']; ?>" /><br> 

    <a href="javascript:;" class="save_fb" id="<?php echo $row['fb_id']; ?>"></a>


        </form>
```

The jQuery:

```
  var id = $(this).attr("id"); 
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: $("input:text[name=fb_titel]", "#myForm-" + id).val() + id,
   url: "save_fb.php",
   success: function(msg)
   {
    $("span#votes_count"+the_id).fadeOut();
    $("span#votes_count"+the_id).html(msg);
    $("span#votes_count"+the_id).fadeIn();
   }
  });
 });
```

Comment: here I get as result 'undefined' ?